# Why am I experimentally getting more small eigenvalues of sample covariance matrices when data come from lower dimensional spaces, and contrary?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-walk, random-matrices

I'm new to Random Matrix Theory (RMT) and I'm playing around (=coding) with generating data in low dimensions, nonlinearly embedding them into a high dimension, and I'm noticing a seeming *intuitively correct* phenomenon. I'd really appreciate some rigorous insight into this, but first let me mathematically state what I'm doing, below.

Say I generate a random sample $X:=\{x_1 \dots x_n \} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and by using a nonlinear map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^p, m < p$, I'm embedding the dataset $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^p$. Next, I'm considering the sample covariance matrix of the embedded data $C:=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi(x_i)\phi(x_i)^{T}$ ($T$ denotes transpose of a matrix or vector, as required.). As in RMT, I take both $n, p$ large, and gradually increase $m$ from small to large, with of course $1 \le m \le p.$ I experimented with many different large values of $n,p$ in the order of thousands.

**I notice the following:**

When the data comes from a low dimension, i.e. $m$ is small, the covariance matrix $C$ of the embedded data in $\mathbb{R}^p$ has a lot of small eigenvalues, and all the eigenvalues tend to be very small ("small" is $<0.01$ in my code), and the lower $m$ is, the more eigenvalues are small. However, when $m$ increases and gradually nears $p$, the number of small eigenvalues tend to decrease and eventually  when $m=p$, $\phi= Id,$ there's no more embedding, and the eigenvalue distribution is what I'd expect it to look like, the [Marcenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution). But as $m \to 1$, the distribution starts to "approach the Dirac mass at $0$" in the sense that more and more eigenvalues  of $C$are getting smaller.

Is there any rigorous explanation for it, at least for some simple/nice embedding $\phi$? Note that it seems intuitively correct, as if in Marcenko-Pastur, you let $\frac{p}{n} \to 0,$ the distribution approaches $\delta_{\sigma^2}$, where the rectangular data matrix $X$ has iid entries with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. But in my case, the difference is that we're non-linearly embedding the data from dimension $m$, and then look at the eigenvalues of the covariance $C:=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi(x_i)\phi(x_i)^{T}$ of the embedded data.

So in essence, I'm looking to see why covariance of data coming from lower dimension $m$ would have more small eigenvalues, and why the number of small eigenvalues goes up when $m$ goes down. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Is the number of small eigenvalues $p-m$?

Comment: @Mick not necessarily, but it'd be my first guess as well. Also it depends on what one calls small (in my case, it's $< 0.01$)

Comment: If your $\phi$ was linear (or affine) then the rank of the matrix $(\phi(x_k))_k$ is m at most. Have you checked the rank with your specific $\phi$?

Comment: @Mick Yes, the rank is often $p (>m)$ even when $m$ is small.

Comment: Actually the (original) Marchenko-Pastur law assumes that the elements of the sample matrix are iid. There are several generalization of this theorem for the case when the elements of a columns are not independent, i.e. $\mathbb Ex_i = 0$ but $\mathbb E[x_ix_i^T] = \Sigma \neq Id. $ , see e.g.  "Bai, Z. D. and Zhou, W. (2008).   Large sample covariance matrices without independence structures in columns. "

Comment: @Mick You're absolutely right that the MP law assumes iid, mean 0, var 1 entries of the rectangular matrix $X$. In my question, when I said I generated a random sample, I used the python command np.random.normal(mu=0, sigma = 1, size(m,n)) that generated an $m\times n$ random matrix with iid $(0,1)$ entries. However, the nonlinear embedding I took was preserving entry-wise independence, because it was a non-linear function of each matrix entry.  I'll erase the line about MP law in my question, it was wrongly stated. Continued to next comment below.

Comment: @Mick(I'm not using chat as it doesn't compile math LaTeX symbols).

Thanks for the paper - I'll take a look. I know of the paper by Baik (not Bai) and Silverstein where they considered $X:= \sqrt{C}Z$, where $Z$ has all mean $0$, var $1$ entries like MP, and $C$ is non-negative definite, so $cov(X)=C$. However, this still means $X=[x_1,\dots x_n]$, where the entries ("features") of each $x_i$ are independent - unrealistic for real data. So I'd like to ask if the paper you mentioned actually works with correlated features too?

Comment: @Mick Since you're working in this field (I'm very new to it), could you also please take a look at this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354288/tracy-widom-type-results-for-asymptotic-distribution-of-the-k-th-largest-eigen ? It's about finding the asymptotic distribution of the $k$ -th largest eigenvalue of $\frac{1}{p}XX'$, when (1) $k$ is fixed and when (2) $k$ grows comparably with $p,n$.

Comment: When k is fixed then the $k^{th}$ ev behaves as the smallest ev, when tends to  as n tends to infinity. As for the other case, when $k/n =c>0$ as n goes to infinity, i dont know from the top of my head, but I know that it concenrates around the $c$ quantile of the MP distribution. The fluctuations are either gaussian or some version of TW I'm not sure. Haven't worked with RMT foa while now...

Comment: @Mick thanks, if you happen to have references in the abive regard, I'd appreciate if you could post - I could take it from there.

Comment: "Tao, Vu: Random Covariance Matrices: Universality Of Local Statistics Of Eigenvalues" would be a good start,  and the Four Moment theorem they describe there. Also, check out "Gaussian fluctuations of eigenvalues in Wigner random matrices, O'Rourke" and "Partial linear eigenvalue statistics for Wigner and sample covariance random matrices, O'Rourke, Soshnikov"

Comment: @Mick Thanks a lot - let me check these references!